# Javascript find and match last item of the string

Tags: javascript, string, substr

I am trying tor write this function that Check if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target). I have used this code but it seems not to work. How can i tweak it?

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  var last = str.substring(-1);
  var last2 = target.substring(-1);
  if (last == last2) return true;
  else if (last !== last2) return false;
}

confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification 
    are easy if both are frozen", "specification") )/*should return "false".
    confirmEnding("Bastian", "n") should return true.
    confirmEnding("Connor", "n") should return false.
    confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification 
    are easy if both are frozen", "specification") should return false.
    confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name") should return true.
    confirmEnding("Open sesame", "same") should return true.
    confirmEnding("Open sesame", "pen") should return false.
    confirmEnding("If you want to save our world, you must hurry. We dont know 
    how much longer we can withstand the nothing", "mountain") should return 
    false.
    Do not use the built-in method .endsWith() to solve the challenge.*/
```

Comment: 'n' === 'n', why should that return false?

Comment: Why should it return false? "frozen" and "specification" both end with "n"

Comment: That's not how [*substring*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.substring) works: '*If either argument is NaN or negative, it is replaced with zero*". Replace `-1` with `str.length - 1`.

Comment: I am doing it as a challenge on a coding bootcamp. and I have passed all tests except this one last string.

Comment: Or use `.substr(-1)` or `.slice(-1)`. But more importantly, you need to learn how to debug your code. You're already partway there, since you know how to use `console.log()`. But take it up a notch and put a `debugger;` line at the beginning of your function. Now if you run it with the developer tools open, it will stop at that breakpoint and you can single step from there and look at your variables as you go. You can also experiment by typing an expression into the JavaScript console. For example, type `"specification".substring(-1)` and you will see that the result is not what you expected.

Comment: @PatrickHund That is the mystery. I have racked my brains the whole day ...but apparently it does not

Comment: @Dr.Apell   I figured out the solution below, the question is worded incorrectly to imply only the last character is compared. It should be comparing the entire string `target` to the corresponding end substring of `str`.

Comment: Just `return (last == last2);` and eliminate the conditional.

Comment: @ Donald. You got it. Thanks all for your help. All contirbutions are great and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass all of the tests with the desired return values, the function should not be comparing the last character of the string, but rather the entire string, `target` to the corresponding end substring of `str`. You need the length of `target` to find the correct starting index for the corresponding substring in `str` as follows:

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
    return str.substring(str.length - target.length) === target)
}
```

Your code is comparing the entire strings. See `substring()` documentation below. `-1` is defaulting to `0` thus returning the substring starting at index `0` and returning the rest of the string (the entire string) since no end index is given. .

> "If either argument is less than 0 or is NaN, it is treated as if it
> were 0."

You can use the length of `target` and subtract it from the length of `str` to get the correct substring for comparison. This will return all of the characters from this index to the end of the string as in `str.length - target.length`though you only really need `target.length` to make the comparison using negative indices. 
Using substring():

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
   var last  = str.substring(str.length- target.length);
   return last === target;
 }
```

simplified:

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
    return str.substring(str.length - target.length) === target)
}
```

[substring() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
**UPDATE: `substr()` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), answer updated to use `substring()` only.**

Comment: Ah almost!! It passed all tests except the example the srting begginning with "walking on water.....",

Comment: @Dr.Apell , I figured out the solution. see EDIT at top.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation. I appreciate that instead of giving only the answer you explained the logic. That helps me learn more. I was completely beffuddled why my code was not working

Comment: Sadly, substr() is being removed from the spec. It's not in the ECMAScript specification. I have not tested the negative index for substring() yet.

Comment: @JoeJohnston good catch, updated to remove deprecated examples and link to deprecation notice.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the ongoing confusion over this case (abbreviated for readability):

```
confirmEnding(
    "Walking on water...both are frozen",
    "specification"
);  // Should return false (why not true?)
```

and also this interesting note:

```
/* Do not use the built-in method .endsWith() to solve the challenge. */
```

I have a hunch about what may have happened.

Double-check the instructions for this question. Are you sure you're supposed to test if the last *character* of each string is the same? It sounds like you are supposed to test if the `src` string ends with the *entire* `target` string.

After all, that is what the `.endsWith()` method does. And it explains the mystery of the test case above.

The [MDN documentation for `.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) doesn't describe the method very well, but the examples it gives make it clear.

With that understanding, you can probably now write the code. I'm not going to write it for you, but I will drop some hints below. I added some code for your tests so that they not only log the result, but also whether they return the desired result. (In the version as written here, all the tests will fail.)

```js
// Return true if str ends with target, false if it does not
function confirmEnding( str, target ) {
    // You can do this in a single return statement
    // with one === comparison in it. The .slice()
    // method will help you here, and you only need
    // to pass a single argument into it.
    // You don't need any if statements, intermediate
    // variables, or anything fancy.
    // There are several other ways to do it too, including
    // the approach shown on the MDN page.
}

function testEnding( str, target, desired ) {
    var result = confirmEnding( str, target );
    console.log(
        '"' + str + '"',
        '"' + target + '"',
        'returns', result,
        result === desired ? 'Good' : 'WRONG!'
    );
}

testEnding( "Bastian", "n", true );
testEnding( "Connor", "n", false );
testEnding( "Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification", false );
testEnding( "He has to give me a new name", "name", true );
testEnding( "Open sesame", "same", true );
testEnding( "Open sesame", "pen", false );
testEnding( "If you want to save our world, you must hurry ); We dont know how much longer we can withstand the nothing", "mountain", false );
```

Comment: That is a very good observation and contribution. It clarifies the challenge . I was flummoxed as to why my code was not working. However you have helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function confirmEnding(a, b) {
    var l1 = a[a.length - 1];
    var l2 = b[b.length - 1];

    return l1 === l2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you're using substring. Try `str.substr` instead of `substring`

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
   return  str.substr(-1) == target.substr(-1);  
 }

console.log(confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification"));
```

Comment: Nope. It passes all six tests with other strings except the example one. I gave.

Comment: Shouldn't this return true? It both ends on n - frozeN and specificatioN

Answer (score 0):

Why have to check if last words are same so:

```js
const confirmEnding = (str, target) => new RegExp(`${target}$`, '').test(str)

console.log(confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification"))

console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "n"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Connor", "n"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification"))
console.log(confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "same"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "pen"))
console.log(confirmEnding("If you want to save our world, you must hurry. We dont know how much longer we can withstand the nothing", "mountain"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = "Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", 
 b = "specification";
  
// your function
const equalLastLetter = (a, b) => a.substr(-1) === b.substr(-1);

console.log(equalLastLetter(a, b))
```

Comment: tried  this too and did not work. It passes all tests except that last example string.

Comment: @Dr.Apell what do you mean? Which string?

Comment: Someone sent me this  code and it passed  all tests.if (string.substr(-target.length) === target) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

Comment: the editor gave me an error message saying it does accept "const"

Comment: @Dr.Apell swap `const` to `var` if it throws an error.

Comment: @Dr.Apell why this should return false?? "Walking on water and developing software from a specification 
are easy if both are frozen", "specification" - BOTH end with 'n', should be TRUE.

Comment: @Dr.Apell  see my answer edit above, the reason why is also stated there as well. You need to compare the entire string, `target` to the end substring of the same length of `str`

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. Unfortunately I cannot up vote cause I have no "reputation" :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
    var last  = str.charAt(str.length-1);
    var last2 = target.charAt(target.length-1);
    return (last == last2);
}
```

Comment: Tried it did not work  It passes all tests except that last string

Comment: Can I see your last test? That will help me find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chatAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

```
function confirmEnding (str, target) {
   var last  = str.charAt(str.length -1);
   var last2 = target.charAt(target.length -1);
   return last === last2 ;
}
```

Comment: why not just use []?

Comment: We can use [] too.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
const confirmEnding = (_str, _target) => _str.charAt(_str.length - 1) === _target.charAt(_target.length - 1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/hsdgjmzw/